# Como generar una condicion en javascript para negar el acceso a una funcion?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Bueno, estoy tratando de crear una condición donde si un elemento select, resulta estar vació, niegue la llamada a una función hecha en ajax, pero mi problema es que no se exactamente como crear esa condición. Aquí esta mi intento de código.

```
function LimpiaEstado() {

var Pais = document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Pais').value;

if (Pais = ''){
    ddl_Perfil_Estado.html('');
    //Aqui intento negar la funcion CatEstado en caso de que este vacio
}

 function CatEstado(Pais) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Talento.ashx?Tipo=Estados&Pais=' + Pais,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ddl_Perfil_Estado').html('');
                    $('#ddl_Perfil_Estado').append('<option value=""> Selecciona..</option>');

                    $.each(data.DatosCatalogoEstado, function (key, val) {
                        $('#ddl_Perfil_Estado').append('<option value="' + val.ID + '">' + val.ESTADO + '</option>');
                    })

                    $('#ddl_Perfil_Estado').selectpicker('refresh');
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $('#ddl_Perfil_Estado').html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
                }
            });
        }
```

Si saben como hacerlo directo con ajax, igual seria de ayuda, o también si saben como hacerlo, sin que sea forzosamente una condición. Cualquier sugerencia o consejo es bienvenido.

Comment: no se si me explique bien con la pregunta?

Comment: no hay otra forma, aparte del if para negar la llamada a una funcion si un campo esta vacio?

Comment: ¿Por qué no verificar la condición **dentro** de la función?

Comment: porque no quiero que la invoque, porque obligaria a llamar al json, y cargar el ajax sin llamar nada, y eso seria un poco obsoleto, como tengo select encadenados, cuando quito un select especifico deja el otro vacio, no se si me explique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué no verificar la condición **dentro** de la función?

```js
function CatEstado() {
    var Pais = document.getElementById('ddl_Perfil_Pais').value;
    if (Pais !== '') {
        $.ajax({
            //Acá va la llamada por AJAX
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: muy cierto, lo probare mañana en la mañana, aunque lo mas lógico es que funcione, gracias.

Comment: bueno, si funciono, pero no como esperaba, debido a que el select comienza en vacio, y ocuparia un callback que diga que al inicio si lo invoque, pero despues no.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos si no quieres cambiar tu código puedes utilizar el **return false**;

```
if (Pais = ''){
    ddl_Perfil_Estado.html('');
    //Aqui intento negar la funcion CatEstado en caso de que este vacio
    return false;
}
```

Así evitaras la llamada ajax, ahora por otro lado esta la otra opción que te presento Mariano.

```
if (Pais = ''){
    $.ajax({
        //Acá va la llamada por AJAX
    });
}
```